# Get NetPBM negative image (Math formula)

Tags: inverse

I have a file of integer values that range from 0 to 255. A value of zero means black pixel while a value of 255 means a white pixel. Values in between are "gray-like colors". I am searching for a way to invert that file so that 255 gets transformed into 0 and 0 gets transformed in 255 (per example), thus allowing me to successfully obtain the negative of the image.

Is there a way to achieve this? I am sure the answer is a simply mathematical formula using modulo but I can't get to it.

For additional please refer to:
[NetPBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)

Comment: @camelccc: I will get negative values that way.... and having in mind the lowest value is zero, I'm gonna make a wild guess and say that's a terrible suggestion.

Comment: and if your range of values is 0 - 255 just how can you get a negative value subtracting a no smaller than 255 from 255 ?

Comment: @camelccc: Ohhh, now I get it. I was reading the answer backwards. I have this terrible habit sry. 
If you transform that comment into an answer I can "select" it and give it karma++ :D Thx! Dumb me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If range of values is 0 - 255

Inverse is 255 - value